# How to make enclosing UIView same size as embedded UIDatePicker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a UIDatePicker in a UIView that looks like this (I changed the background color to red so it would stand out for this question):

[image]

I want the UIView to fit around the UIDatePicker so there is no red.  Here is my code:

```
-(void) showModalCalendar:(int)tag {

UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216)]; 
popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

//  the full UIDatePicker
datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
datePicker.frame=CGRectMake(0,44,320, 216);

//  set the locale to en-GB for testing!
NSLocale *uk = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];
[datePicker setLocale:uk];

if(tag == 202)  {
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
    [datePicker setTag:205];
}
else if(tag == 203)  {
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    [datePicker setTag:206];
}

[datePicker setMinuteInterval:15];

[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[popoverView addSubview:datePicker];

popoverContent.view = popoverView;

popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];

popoverController.delegate = (id)self;

[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 264) animated:NO];

switch (tag)  {  //  displays the popover datepicker
    case 202:  //  appointment start time
        [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:boApptStart.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
        break;
    case 203:  //  appointment end time
        [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:boApptEnd.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
        break;
}
```

}

What do I need to do or change?

**UPDATE - we're getting closer! (I think) :D**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
datePicker.frame=CGRectMake(0,44,320, 216);
```

To this line

```
datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216);
```

And then set the contentSizeForViewInPopover on your view controller, like this

```
popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 216.0);
```

Comment: I got it...  code below:
 [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 216) animated:NO];  //  264

Comment: Thank you... would have taken me days of futzing with it... :D